# For bond dissociation energies (BDEs) of double and triple bonds, is number shown in tables for that second or third bond? Or all of them?

Tags: thermodynamics, bond

Simple, 'dumb' question....   Is the kJ/mol number given in tables of bond strengths or bond dissociation energies , when it comes to double and triple bonds, just for the 'last' bond or for both (or all three) together?

Comment: The tabulated numbers are for dissociating the bond, i.e., breaking it, not just weakening it.

Comment: As for you are interested on this, you should have reasoned about this by considering the values, isn't?

Comment: I did reason about this, Alchimista, I just wasn't sure...

Answer (score 4):

They're for the entire bond (so for a triple bond, all 3).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy#Strongest_bonds_and_weakest_bonds), it can be defined as

> The standard enthalpy change when [a bond, be it single, double, or triple] is cleaved by homolysis to give fragments A and B, which are usually radical species

So you get two fragments as your final state.

Comment: The part about homolytic cleavage is also important because for some bonds (like HCl) under the right conditions, heterolytic cleavage is much easier. For one thing, it does not produce radicals.